# What is the scientific and common name of this bug?

Tags: zoology, entomology, species-identification

Captured this under my stereo microscope. Much more beautiful than appearing on my camera sensor.
Can someone help me identify it and explore more?
Also is it having a compound eye ?

Location: New Delhi.

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a hemiptera, looks like a stink bug, though I don't recognize the color. And yeah, those are compound eyes.

Comment: Pentatomidae(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentatomidae).

Great pic! can you tell us the geographic location this found?

Comment: @DevashishDas New Delhi, I found it near my table lamp on first floor in evening, where I have kept some plants. Then I took a leafe, and gently placed it on it, and photographed under my microscope.   I found that it became stable as soon as it came in contact with the leaf, otherwise it was moving here and there and jumping a lot. And thanks for the link.

Comment: @DevashishDas Post your comment as an answer so that it can be accepted by the OP and the question can be closed.

Comment: @TheLastWord That's not the answer though, the question asks for species, and pentatomidae is the family name.

Answer (score 4):

Definitely appears to be [Pentatomidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentatomidae) (as others have pointed out) due to shield-like, broad bodies. With over 4500 species and larval stages demonstrating significant variability even within species, ID can be difficult without knowing specific fauna, size, habitat, etc.

The OP doesn't list a size, but because OP is viewing under a scope, I assumed this is a fairly tiny species.

I came across this similar-looking unknown species (simply labeled "PK03") of the genus ***Eysarcoris***

[image]

<sup>Credit: [CBG Photography Group, Centre for Biodiversity Genomics](https://v3.boldsystems.org/index.php/Taxbrowser_Taxonpage?taxid=660235)</sup>

The *Eysarcoris* genus is present in India (e.g., see [indiabiodiversity.org](https://indiabiodiversity.org/observation/show/1731133) with example of "two-spotted sesame bug")

A similar species well known throughout Europe is [*Stagonomus venustissimus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stagonomus_venustissimus) (previously classified as *Eysarcoris*):

[image]

<sup>Credit: Jose Manuel Sesma (2016); appears to be originally posted [here](https://www.biodiversidadvirtual.org/insectarium/Stagonomus-venustissimus-(Schrank-1776)-img820834.html)</sup>

I cannot say if either of these species is correct (doubtful), but I think they are closer than the other provided answer.

I'll update if I find anything specific.

Answer (score 2):

It belongs to [Pentatomidae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentatomidae) family. More on the Wiki page

[image]

Comment: That's correct, but pentatomidae is the family name, and the question asks for species.

Comment: The answer will be more useful for future reference if you add some rationale for your determination.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your other question about the eye:

Yes, shield bugs (Pentatomidae), like most insects, have [compound eyes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_eye).

- [Buschbeck and Friedrich (2008)](https://evolution-outreach.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1007/s12052-008-0086-z)<sup>1</sup> discuss this highly conserved trait found in most arthropods.

Also, the red dot medial and nearby the eye? That's an [**ocellus**](https://www.amentsoc.org/insects/glossary/terms/ocelli), a simple eye.

[image]

<sup>[Oregon Department of Agriculture](https://www.oregon.gov/ODA/shared/Documents/Publications/IPPM/StinkBugGuide.pdf)</sup>

---

1: Buschbeck, E.K. and Friedrich, M., 2008. Evolution of insect eyes: tales of ancient heritage, deconstruction, reconstruction, remodeling, and recycling. *Evolution: Education and Outreach*, 1(4), pp.448-462.